# Split Single Column into many based on term that varies

Tags: bash

I've searched questions that have already been asked and couldn't find something that matched for what I'm trying to solve.

I am on a Mac, using terminal. I would like this to run as part of another script written in bash.

I have a CSV file that has a single column. Under each "header" will contain different numbers of devices depending on the output. The headers (SerialNumber, DeviceName, PurchaseDate) will always be constant.

SerialNumbers
A1B2C3D4E5F6
SASIUWOI9828
I3I6K36H78SK
DeviceName
This one has a short name
This one has a long name
This one has a medium name
PurchaseDate
2016-02-19
2016-02-01
2016-02-12

Desired output

SerialNumbers,DeviceName,PurchaseDate
A1B2C3D4E5F6,This one has a short name, 2016-02-19
SASIUWOI9828,This one has a long name,2016-02-01 
I3I6K36H78SK,This one has a medium name,2016-02-12

Here is my source file, if it helps

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wapjqbi1v3oah3p/tobecorrected.csv?dl=0

Comment: Should "PurchaseDate" also be output as a header?

Comment: Edited to show change. Thank you!

Comment: Could you have additional headers besides (SerialNumber, DeviceName, PurchaseDate)? If so, please edit your question.

Comment: You wrote "The headers (SerialNumber, DeviceName, PurchaseDate) will always be constant.". However, the fields DeviceName and PurchaseDate do not appear in your link file. Could you clarify that?

Comment: I was trying to take what was done here, and apply it as part of the learning process so I'm not just copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `pr` exists in your OS, but this is the easiest way

```
$ pr -3ts, file

SerialNumbers,DeviceName,PurchaseDate
A1B2C3D4E5F6,This one has a short name,2016-02-19
SASIUWOI9828,This one has a long name,2016-02-01
I3I6K36H78SK,This one has a medium name,2016-02-12
```

Comment: Love the simplicity. Any chance you can explain the syntax? At first I thought it took a column and split it into 3 columns, but that doesn't seem to be the case. If I have a document thet needs to eb split into 5 columns, I can't simply change the 3 to a 5.

Comment: It does, change 3 to 5 for five colums but your format should be consistent.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I posted the source file (with parts of fields removed) if you'd be so kind to take a quick look. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @cducasse, while the `pr` command expects a UNIX text file, your text file is in DOS format. Try this workaround: `cat file | tr -d '\015' | pr -5ts,`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the headers appear always in the same order you can use the following script `convert.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
C1="`awk '/SerialNumbers/{flag=1}/DeviceName/{flag=0}flag' $1`"
C2="`awk '/DeviceName/{flag=1}/PurchaseDate/{flag=0}flag' $1`"
C3="`awk '/PurchaseDate/,0' $1`"
paste <(echo "$C1") <(echo "$C2") <(echo "$C3") --delimiters ','
```

Example:

```
./convert.sh test.txt
```

Output:

```
SerialNumbers,DeviceName,PurchaseDate
A1B2C3D4E5F6,This one has a short name,2016-02-19
SASIUWOI9828,This one has a long name,2016-02-01
I3I6K36H78SK,This one has a medium name,2016-02-12
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk will handle the headers in any order and with variable length data following the header:

```
awk  '
/SerialNumbers/ {sn=1; dn=0; pd=0}
/DeviceName/ {sn=0; dn=1; pd=0}
/PurchaseDate/ {sn=0; dn=0; pd=1}

sn==1 {snl[++snc]=$0}
dn==1 {dnl[++dnc]=$0}
pd==1 {pdl[++pdc]=$0}

END{
    max=snc>dnc?snc:dnc;
    max=pdc>max?pdc:max;
    for (i=1;i<=max;i++)
        print snl[i]","dnl[i]","pdl[i]
}' file
```

---

*Edit*

Given your [example file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wapjqbi1v3oah3p/tobecorrected.csv?dl=0) you can do:

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]+:/ {sub(/:/,""); idx=$0; arr[idx]=$0; next}
{arr[idx]=arr[idx]","$1}
END{
    for (id in arr) print arr[id]}' file.txt | rs -c',' -C',' -T | sed 's/,$//'
```

Prints:

```
serialNumber,bluetoothAddress,wifiAddress,enclosureColor,totalDiskCapacity
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQF,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
```

If you have fields that have spaces, replace `{arr[idx]=arr[idx]","$1}` with:

```
{  
    sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    arr[idx]=arr[idx]","$0
}
```

Then it prints:

```
serialNumber,bluetoothAddress,wifiAddress,enclosureColor,totalDiskCapacity
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQF,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583 B59,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQG,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
DMPQD,0.214583,0.214583,#b4b5b9,1585
```

(Note the longer line with B59 added)

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety, here's a solution which does not use `awk`. Note that you'll need a trailing newline in your input file for this to output correctly, and I'm assuming that the headers and their order are known beforehand (otherwise the first `if` statement will need changed).

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"

declare -a arr=("SerialNumbers" "DeviceName" "PurchaseDate")
declare -A output

col=0
while read -r line
do
    if [[ "${arr[$col]}" == "$line" ]]; then # header
        col=$((col+1))
        row=1
        output[$((row-1)),$((col-1))]=$line
    else
        output[$row,$((col-1))]=$line
        row=$((row+1))
    fi
done < "$filename"

# print results
for ((i=0;i<row;i++)) do
    for ((j=0;j<col;j++)) do
        printf "${output[$i,$j]}"
        if (( j < col-1)); then
            printf ","
        fi
    done
    echo
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.sh example.txt
SerialNumbers,DeviceName,PurchaseDate
A1B2C3D4E5F6,This one has a short name,2016-02-19
SASIUWOI9828,This one has a long name,2016-02-01
I3I6K36H78SK,This one has a medium name,2016-02-12
```